# Access Tomcat running on Mac os x 10.6.8

Tags: macos, tomcat

I have my web application running on tomcat server in a Mac OS 10.6.8. The application is running fine and I can access the application locally using localhost or 127.0.0.1

The System is connected to a LAN and has a IP address like 10.*.*.* .

My problem is when I try to access the application from a different system connected to the same LAN, using the real ip (10....), the application is not accessible.

Is there any configuration that I have to do so that the tomcat server will be accessible from a different system.

I was earlier using Windows system and tomcat was accessible to other system without any problem.

But now I have shifted my server to Mac OS, and the server is not accessible outside.

Comment: When you say "the application is not accessible", what are the symptoms?

Comment: When I access the application using a browser, it just keep trying to access that one. After a long time, around 1 or 2 minute, the browser displays "Internal server error- server connection terminated".

Answer (score 2):

First check that Tomcat is listening on the public IP (it will be by default). You can confirm this with `netstat -na | grep 8080`

Second, check that the OSX firewall (System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Advanced - java should appear in the list and it should be set to allow incoming connections) isn't blocking incoming connections on the relevant port - I assume 8080.